# how to disable indent for close braces in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, indentation

when I type {} in my code for examples it likes:

```
foreach(var item in items) {
            }
```

but I want

```
foreach(var item in items) {
}
```

Even I did options -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting -> Indentation -> unclick `indent open and close braces`. So what's wrong with me?

Comment: Are you using any other addins, such as Resharper?

Comment: @MatthewWatson no, I use nothing above, use pure Visual Studio.

Comment: ```Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D,``` which indents the whole document.

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN, those commands delete whole my codes :(

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Basic -> Advanced -> Editor Help -> ensure "Pretty Listing (reformatting) of code" is enabled.

Comment: yeah, it is already enabled, but still not works

Comment: it seems your visual studio settings are messed up. you can reset your settings in :
Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all Settings

Comment: @ I dit every you guys suggested but it stills not worked:

Comment: check one thing else. in text editior -> c# -> code style -> formatting -> general 
make sure all checkboxes are checked.

Comment: also in c# -> code style -> formatting -> New Lines

Again make sure all checkboxes are checked

Comment: @ yeah, I did everything but still like close braces  is still indenting, I also did reset every other options